# Can you fork Magento CE 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, git

Very simple question, can you fork Magento CE 1.9.x?

Comment: Means? we did not get ur question ?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

Comment: Thanks for the link, so people are forking it and releasing it publicly for free via github. It's not very clear what OSL allows and doesn't allow.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple answer: no

Magento 1 is not officially available on a version control platform.

Comment: What about https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror?

Comment: That is a community maintained Magento 1 mirror. So it is up to a community member to keep it up to date whenever a new version comes out. Also it doesn't accept any pull requests or issues, because it should represent the official Magento 1 releases (and there is no upstream towards Magento).